# Using multiple values of an argument in Clap

Tags: rust, clap

I am using Clap and my YAML file has the following:

```
args:
- DIRECTORY
    help: one or more directories
    required: true
    multiple: true
```

In my main.rs, I want to get the name of each of the directory passed as an argument and do something like

```
dir_names.push(name_of_the_directory);
```

where `dir_names` is a vector and `name_of_the_directory` is a string slice.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using the [`values_of`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.31.1/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.values_of) method:

```
let dir_names: Vec<&str> = m.values_of("output").unwrap().collect();
```

In current version of `clap` (4.4.7), this has been replaced by [`get_many`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.get_many):

```
let dir_names: Vec<&str> = m.get_many ("output").unwrap().collect();
```

Comment: The `values_of` is replaced by `value_source` in the latest (currently 4.4.7) version of [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/).

Comment: @PéterSzilvási actually it's replaced by `get_many`, edited.